A question about terminology in evolution problems.
The heat equation is
\begin{align}
u_t=-\Delta u\\
u(0)=u_0
\end{align}
and the solution (formally) is $u(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-t\Delta}u_0$. Formally, $\mathrm{e}^{-t\Delta}u_0=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\widehat{u_0}\right)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\right)*u_0$
Question 1. $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\right)$ has a name? Is the Green function?
Question 2. This function is defined of this form? $]0,\infty[\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)\colon t\mapsto P_t(\cdot):=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t|\xi|^2}\right)(\cdot)$
